# Json data using Hashmap and Array List

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am fetching data from DB and adding into Hashmap and then the Hashmap data to Array List to obtain JSON data. But I am not getting the output as expected. Child values should be added to the Hashmap based on the parent.

Java code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class HaspmapEx
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
        ResultSet rs2 = null;
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> outMap= new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

        try{  

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","REF","REF");  

            String qstr = "select distinct PARENT_ORG_NAME from demo_org_data";
            String qstr1 = "select distinct org_lev1,org_lev2 from demo_org_data";

            pst=connection.prepareStatement(qstr);  
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            pst2 = connection.prepareStatement(qstr1);
            rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) { 

                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> category = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 
                 category.put("label", rs.getString(1));

                 while (rs2.next())
                 {
                     LinkedHashMap<String, Object> category1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                     LinkedHashMap<String, Object> category2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                     category1.put("label", rs2.getString(1));
                     category1.put("label", rs2.getString(2));
                     category1.put("category", category2);
                     list1.add(category1);
                 }
                 category.put("category",list1);
                 list.add(category);
}

}
        catch (SQLException sql) {
            System.out.println("SQLException occurred while fetching the data");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while fetching the data");
        }

        outMap.put("category", list);
       System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(outMap).toString()); 

    }
}
```

Output for the above Java code :

```
"category": [{
               "label": "CEO",
               "category": [{
                   "label": "CFO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "Payables"
                   }
               }, {
                   "label": "CFO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "Receivables"
                   }
               }, {
                   "label": "CIO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "HR"
                   }
               }, {
                   "label": "CIO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "PR"
                   }
               }, {
                   "label": "CTO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "Architect"
                   }
               }, {
                   "label": "CTO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "Project Manager"
                   }
               }, {
                   "label": "CTO",
                   "category": {
                       "label": "QA Manager"
                   }
               }]
           }]
       }
```

I want the output as shown below. The Parent-Child relationship can be clearly seen in the JSON data below

```
"category": [{
        "label": "CEO",
        "category": [{
            "label": "CTO",
            "category": [{
                "label": "Proj. Manager"
            }, {
                "label": "Q & A Manager"

            }, {
                "label": "Architect"

            }]
        }, {
            "label": "CFO",
                           "category": [{
                "label": "Payables"

            }, {
                "label": "Receivables"

            }]
        }, {
            "label": "CIO",
            "category": [{
                "label": "PR"

            }, {
                "label": "HR"

            }]
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: Your root object has a label and a category and category has list of labels. Not clear on how you're modeling your data, but you'll need to go along similar lines.

Comment: The "expected" JSON is invalid. You have redundant comma in all the labels: `{
                "label": "Proj. Manager",
            }`

Comment: the code is not very clear (there is `catch` without `try`) more importantly, `list1` and `outMap` are undefined. and why do you use `LinkedHashMap` instead of regular `HashMap`?

Comment: it is not clear to me what is being fetched from the DB. is PARENT_ORG_NAME = CEO? or is it also CFO and the others? please give example of fetched result sets

Comment: I had removed the next set of keys and values . Sorry, Forgot to remove the commas. Initially I had shared half of the java code. Now,  I have shared the complete java code above. I have used LinkedHashMap to maintain the insertion order of elements.

Comment: The table has 3 columns :                                               1.PARENT_ORG_NAME - CEO  ( parent for ORG_LEV1 categories)                                                                      2.ORG_LEV1 - CFO , CIO , CTO  (parent for ORG_LEV2 categories)                                                  3.ORG_LEV2 -  Payables,Receivables (CFO is the parent) , HR,PR (CIO is parent) , Architect,Project Manager,QA Manager (CTO is parent) . There are totally 7 rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a list of categories and search for past occurences of org_lev1. I added a seperate method for that.

see complete solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;

    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> parentCategory = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","REF","REF");  
        String qstr = "select distinct PARENT_ORG_NAME from demo_org_data";
        String qstr1 = "select distinct org_lev1,org_lev2 from demo_org_data";

        pst = connection.prepareStatement(qstr);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        pst2 = connection.prepareStatement(qstr1);
        rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
            parentCategory.put("label", rs.getString(1));
            parentCategory.put("category", parentList);
            while (rs2.next()) {
                String org_lev1 = rs2.getString(1);
                String org_lev2 = rs2.getString(2);
                Map<String, Object> subCategory = searchCategoryByLabel(parentList, org_lev1);
                if (subCategory == null) {
                    subCategory = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                    subCategory.put("label", org_lev1);
                    subCategory.put("category", new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>());
                    parentList.add(subCategory);
                }
                List<Map<String, String>> subList = (List<Map<String, String>>)subCategory.get("category");
                subList.add(Collections.singletonMap("label", org_lev2));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.out.println("SQLException occurred while fetching the data");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while fetching the data");
    }

    Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> outMap = 
            Collections.singletonMap("category", Collections.singletonList(parentCategory));
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(outMap).toString());
}

public static Map<String, Object> searchCategoryByLabel(List<Map<String, Object>> list, String label)
{
    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
        if (map.containsKey("label") && map.get("label").toString().equals(label)) {
            return map;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I got output:

```
{"category":[{"label":"CEO","category":[{"label":"CTO","category":[{"label":"Q \u0026 A Manager"},{"label":"Architect"},{"label":"Proj. Manager"}]},{"label":"CFO","category":[{"label":"Payables"},{"label":"Receivables"}]},{"label":"CIO","category":[{"label":"PR"},{"label":"HR"}]}]}]}
```

(hope you will appriciate the time I took to develop this)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sharon :)  The output is perfect. Appreciate the time you took to develop it. So fast!!!

Answer (score 0):

You define a new `category` map for each entry in `rs`, so you will end up with several `category` maps.  You want to put them inside one map that contains the `category` map and also `rs.getString(1)` so you need to define another (different) `Map<String, Object>` (call it `allCategories`) before the main loop, and then put in it `rs.getString(1)` and also `category` once it is populated.

Comment: I tried as u said but  I'm not getting the output as expected. May be I'm going wrong somewhere.